# Function that gets input information from form - OOP

Tags: php, oop

I am looking to create a **PHP** function that will get input values from any input that I place on the page.

for example, rather than writing

```
$this->name = $_POST['name'];
$this->email = $_POST['email'];
$this->address = $_POST['address'];
```

etc..

I would rather have a function that will get any data from the form, because with a possibility of adding more forms later on, I don't want to have to change the code too much.

If this is possible, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think it's not a good practice...

Comment: perhaps not, but without knowing the purpose of the function it's hard to say.

Comment: you can just use a for/foreach loop through $_POST to get each item but you'll then need to process them/match against the post variable name

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an array containing all the form values that were posted, to go through them all you can do this:

```
foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {
    echo sprintf('%s: %s<br />', $field, $value);
}
```

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense. Is there any way of then assigning these to a different value for each one?

Comment: *bam* XSS vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understood what you want, but i think it is what you wanted. Use the code below

```
<?php
class test{
function raj(){
$this->name = $_POST['name'];
$this->email = $_POST['email'];
$this->address = $_POST['address'];
return($this->name);
}

}
$r = new test;
echo $r->raj(); // Will output the name
?>
```

Hope this helps you